# Programmatically creating a native Outlook Distribution List

Tags: c#, exchange-server, file-format

If I share a distribution list in Outlook in 'Outlook Format' the result is a .msg file. Double-clicking on this file opens the Distribution List window in Outlook.

I have an app that contains a list of email contacts and my user wants to be able to send this list out as an Outlook Distribution List.

Now, I know I can export it as a .csv file so that the user can import this, but that's not what's required.

So, to the question: does anyone know if it is possible to generate this .msg file in the correct format from a 3rd-party application for use by Outlook?

If it of any import or relevance, the app is an ASP.NET C# WebApplication

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Extended MAPI for that (C++ or Delphi only, use `OpenIMsgOnIStg`, etc.) and set a bunch of named properties.
You can also use [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/) (I am its author) and create a distribution list on top of an MSG file using `RDOSession.CreateMessageFromMsgFile` (assuming Outlook/MAPI system are installed):

```
  set Session = CreateObject("Redemption.RDOSession")
  set DL = Session.CreateMessageFromMsgFile("c:\temp\TestDL.Msg", "IPM.DistLIst", 1)
  DL.AddMemberEx "Joe The User", "user@test.demo", "SMTP"
  DL.Save
```